# React: Delete cookie when user closes the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-cookie

I'm using the library react-cookie (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) and I want to delete the user cookies when the browser or tab is closed. I used ComponentWillUnmount in my Approuter, but that doesn't work when the browser is closed. Anyone know how to achieve this?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from '../data/history';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';


class AppRouter extends React.Component{

static propTypes = {
    cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
};


constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

componentWillMount(){
    const {cookies} = this.props;
    cookies.remove('userInfo');
}

render(){
    return(
        <Router history={history}>
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <div className="main-container">
                    <Switch>
                        //routes
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer/>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
}

export default withCookies(AppRouter);
```

The router does receive the cookies so why can't I remove it with componentWillUnmount? And how do I remove them?

Comment: Wouldn't the cookie be deleted if you remove the expiration date? AFAIK a cookie without expiration date lasts only for that particular session.

Comment: My cookie doesn't have expiration data @Mirakurun

Comment: Well, then it should expire by the end of the session. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33748

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't see that you want to delete it also on tab close. This one won't work for that case, yes.

Comment: Yeah no problem, @mirakurun

Comment: thanks very much bro...your code helped me a lot...to logout n remove cookies

Answer (score 2):

When you create cookie.
please set expires to 0.
e.g

```
cookies.set('userInfo', name, { expires: 0 });
```

Then this cookie will be expired when browser closed.

Comment: This works when the browser is completely is shut down, but not when the tab is closed. Any tips for that?

Answer (score 0):

Old post but today I was needing this and did some search and found nothing, until I came up with an easy solution.
Posting here hoping it will help someone.

You just need to add the following to your **'index.js'**:

```
const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
  Cookies.remove('userinfo');
};
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really React specific but you can use this :

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => 
{  
    ev.preventDefault();
    cookies.remove('userInfo');
});
```

Maybe call it on mount so you can have access your class instance.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you...

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener(
        "beforeunload",
        cookies.remove('userInfo')
    );
}
```